# Flot tick labels not displaying properly in .toDataURL() export

Tags: flot

I am using Flot version 0.8.3 to display several types of charts. I give users an option to export the chart from the canvas using `.toDataURL('img/png')`.

The exported images were not showing the tick axis labels. I eventually figured out this was because the labels were rendering in html and not on the canvas. So, I added jquery.flot.canvas.js and set `options.canvas = true` just prior to exporting.  The labels now appear in the exported image, but the x-axis tick labels overlap each other.

[image: overlapping x-axis tick labels]

I then added jquery.flot.tickrotor.js and set `options.xaxis.rotateTicks = 135` to rotate the labels. The labels do still appear in the exported image, and they are correctly rotated, but they have lost the font size, appearing much smaller than other text, and the x-axis ticks have disappeared from the grid. (I have set the font with `options.xaxis.font.size = 24`, the same font size I've given all text in the canvas.)

[image: rotated but tiny x-axis tick labels with missing ticks]

What do I need to do to include the tick labels in the exported image without overlapping and, if rotated, at the correct font size?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle so we (I) can play a bit?

Comment: @Mark, will this do: http://jsfiddle.net/N89E9/2/?

Comment: @Mark, apologies for wasting your time. If I had read the README more closely, I'd have noticed `xaxis.rotateTicksFont`. The fonts are now properly sized, but still missing the vertical tick line across the grid.

Comment: No troubles, glad you got it sorted, I actually just started to look...

Comment: @Mark, thanks. Any idea what might be causing the tick itself to disappear?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the plugin.  He draws the tick labels directly on the canvas and to avoid getting the original html ticks he clears them using  `opts.ticks = [];`.  Having those ticks present control the gridlines, though.

Comment: @Mark, any thoughts how to get around this?

Comment: Hmm, I would start by filing a bug with the plugin's author.  I'll try and take a further look at the source code of the plugin this morning; the fix will involve modifying it.

Comment: I guess it's time to lose my GitHub virginity. ;)

Comment: @Mark, apologies for being a pest, but have you had any further insight into this? I haven't had any luck finding a solution, but I have to admit I get a bit lost trying to follow everything that's happening in the flot code. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have succeeded in patching flot as described at https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor/issues/11, and that seems to have taken care of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues here:

(1) First, the rotated tick label text was tiny. I was initially setting the tick label font with `xaxis.font`, which is ignored by *jquery.flot.tickrotor.js*. As stated in [the plugin's README](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor/blob/master/README), declare the font in the `xaxis.rotateTicksFont` option instead.

(2) Second, when rotating tick labels, the vertical tick lines would disappear. As pointed out by Mark in the comments, this is due to a bug on on line 77 of *jquery.flot.tickrotor.js*: `opts.ticks = [];`.  ([A bug report has been filed.](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor/issues/11))

In the meantime, until the bug gets resolved, to fix the issue I have patched *jquery.flot.js* as follows:

```
/jquery.flot.js
Index: assets/javascript/lib/jquery/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js
===================================================================
--- assets/javascript/lib/jquery/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js    (revision 13829)
+++ assets/javascript/lib/jquery/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js    (working copy)
@@ -2030,8 +2030,9 @@

             for (var j = 0; j < axes.length; ++j) {
                 var axis = axes[j], box = axis.box,
-                    t = axis.tickLength, x, y, xoff, yoff;
-                if (!axis.show || axis.ticks.length == 0)
+                    t = axis.tickLength, x, y, xoff, yoff,
+                    rTicks = axis.rotatedTicks || axis.ticks;
+                if (!axis.show || rTicks.length == 0)
                     continue;

                 ctx.lineWidth = 1;
@@ -2080,8 +2081,8 @@
                 ctx.strokeStyle = axis.options.tickColor;

                 ctx.beginPath();
-                for (i = 0; i < axis.ticks.length; ++i) {
-                    var v = axis.ticks[i].v;
+                for (i = 0; i < rTicks.length; ++i) {
+                    var v = rTicks[i].v;

                     xoff = yoff = 0;
```

Problem solved.